# Let $x \in R$. Then, prove that $x^2+|x-6|>5$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, absolute-value

I have tried to prove this statement by utilizing the proof by cases method. My cases are (1)$x=6$, (2)$x>6$ and (3)$x<6$.

For (3) for some reason it's not true

Case (1):
For $x>6$, I know that $x^2+x>11$ is true

Case (2):
For $x=6$, clearly $36>5$

Case (3):

For $x<6$, $x^2+x>11$ it is not true. (e.g 1,2,3...)

Thanks

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: It is clear that you have tried to solve this problem, but it would help if you wrote out your full attempt here (using MathJax), so that users might be able to help you spot exactly what and where your mistake was.

Comment: Well...if you have found a counterexample, then you are done.  The claim would be false so there's be nothing to prove.  But have you really found a counterexample?  If, say, we take $x=1$ then the left hand is $1^2+|1-6|=1+5=6>5$ so the claim appears to hold for $x=1$, right?

Comment: Yeah, how do I go about proving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case $(3)$, notice that if $x<6$ then $|x-6|=6-x$. Then, your inequality becomes
$$x^2+6-x>5$$
$$x^2-x+1>0$$
$$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}>0$$
which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt seems incorrect to me when you analyze the case $3$.

Note that, if $x≤6$, then you have:

$$
\begin{align}
&x^2-x+6-5>0\wedge x≤6\\
\implies &\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 34 >0.
\end{align}
$$